# Know the city of origin from an italian passport

Tags: europe, italy, italian-citizens

I have an Italian passport because I have dual citizenship. I was wondering if there is a way to know which city of Italy has my information.

I guess I can ask the consulate or check where my ancestors are from but I wanted to know if there is a faster way to get this information!

Comment: What do you mean by "your information"? What exactly are your looking for?

Comment: Ask your local Italian mission to check the Anagrafe for you. FYI it'll take time.

Answer (score 9):

Your passport hold three information that can be useful to you, but as other peoples already wrote (both in answers and in comments), it all depends on where you were born.

That said, this is what you should have on your italian passport:

- Page 2, the one with the photos, has **Place of birth**. This is, obviously, the place you are supposed to be born for the Italian government.
- Page 3, there are your residences. They are the place where you are supposed to be living, but if you are living abroad and never lived in Italy it will be less than useful
- Page 4 (and 5, actually), and this could be interesting for you: those are the pages reserved to the authority who has redacted your passport. This is the authority that was in charge of your data and your identity as an italian citizen at the moment of your passport printing; mine, for example, report "Questura di Varese", meaning "Police headquarters of the city of Varese". Keep in mind that this not means your ancestors are from there, anyway.

Generally speaking, finally, all citizens data are centralized and your residence points to the city who is currently "responsible" for you, but that has not necessarely anything to do with your parent's place of origin.

Comment: P.S. I'm using terms a bit liberally, here; I'm just trying to give a rough idea of things, I've got not enough legal experience to know the right terms in Italian, go figure translating them to English :-D

Answer (score 5):

It depends on where you were born. If you were born in Italy, then the Italian "anagrafe" will have a copy of a document stating the details of your birth.

If you were born abroad instead, as pointed out by another user, there may not even be a city which has your info. The registration of your birth went most probably through a consulate, which comunicated your data to the Italian government.  If this was your case, there is a high chance that your data is stored in some archive in the Italian "Esteri" Ministry (aka "Farnesina"), which is physically in Rome, but I'm positive that nowadays a lot of data is being digitally stored.